# How can I find which Jekyll themes are available as gems?

Tags: rubygems, themes, jekyll

How can I find which Jekyll themes are available as gems?

I read in the Jekyll documentation that themes packaged as Ruby gems are cleaner to work with, since their files do not clutter my blog directory tree.

A web search yielded http://jekyllthemes.org/, but as far as I can tell, that site does not indicate whether or not a theme is packaged as a gem.

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll themes packaged as a gem *will most likely* have a `<theme_name>.gemspec` file checked into their repository.

Also running a search in `rubygems.org` will yield some results..
e.g. : https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=jekyll+theme

Comment: Thanks, the Ruby Gems search was productive. However, I can't seem to use any of them because they don't seem to have post layouts. I posted another SO question about it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609857/why-is-the-post-layout-missing-from-so-many-themes.

Comment: all of the themes you find in the search query above is used by GitHub Pages which also uses a plugin named `jekyll-default-layout` that automatically uses available layouts..

Comment: What do you mean by "uses available layouts"? The Wordpress to Jekyll converter specified layouts "post", "main", and "page". "main" is the front page with the list of articles, and probably the most important one. Does `jekyll-default-layout` address that somehow?

Comment: Sorry that i wasn't clear with the previous comment. What I meant is that themes at GitHub have a base layout named `default.html`. The plugin makes the page fallback to this layout if Jekyll encounters a missing layout. Minima has three layouts: `default`, `page` and `post`. `main` is only the name of the stylesheet file.